# How do I style the sidebar of gmaps4rails, and move it around on the page?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I want to move the sidebar UL to a different location on the page and make it look different. I have tried using CSS to float it to the left and right of the map. The best I was able to do was move the UL to the top above the map instead of below it.

Comment: it's just a css issue, the gem just needs the selector of your sidebar, so you can add whatever styles you need

Comment: Ok I will play with it some more. It didn't seem to respond to CSS so I thought I was missing something, but apparently I just need to play with it some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually much easier than I thought. I had a problem with an unclosed div tag creating the issue I experienced.

Just create a Div with the markers_list id and apply liberal CSS.